# gdb,why "next" show each source line twice?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

everyone,when use "next" instruction within gdb,i found each line of sourcecode display twice-----i am quite sure,these code are not in any loop.this is the phenomenon:

```
(gdb) frame
#0  ap_get_client_block (r=0x8560d48, 
    buffer=0xb68501b7 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Root><OperCode>SMS101</OperCode><AppId>SMSMsgFilterReq</AppId><Req><UserMobile>13925237429</UserMobile><SendMsg>abc圲34¨圲23a露07\214圲21￠＜237朲11?东215圲10°＜214朲27￥応227露07\214正常,hao"..., bufsiz=81920) at http_filters.c:1540
1540        if (r->remaining < 0 || (!r->read_chunked && r->remaining == 0)) {
(gdb) n
1544        bb = apr_brigade_create(r->pool, r->connection->bucket_alloc);
(gdb) 
1545        if (bb == NULL) {
(gdb) 
1544        bb = apr_brigade_create(r->pool, r->connection->bucket_alloc);
(gdb) 
1545        if (bb == NULL) {
```

-----the line 1544,1545 are not in any loop,but they got repeated. 
May anybody enlighten me?

Comment: What optimisation options was your binary compiled with? Optimisations can reorder things, meaning that your code isn't executed in the order you think it might be.

Comment: to Philip Kendall,this is my gcc and options(no optimisztion?):gcc/g++ version:4.1.2 20080704 (RedHat4.1.2-46) ,                   complile options:-g -Wall  -I../../include -I../bayes\-I/usr/local/apache2/include  -D__LINUX__

Answer (score 14):

What level of optimisation did you have when you compiled this?

Even a minimal level of optimisation can cause your debugger to jump around the source lines like crazy as the compiler inlines, reorders and generally plays with your code.

Comment: to Tom Tanner,this is my option:gcc/g++ version:4.1.2 20080704 (RedHat4.1.2-46) , complile options:-g -Wall -I../../include -I../bayes\-I/usr/local/apache2/include -D__LINUX__                        _________does gcc/g++ make some optimisation default for us？

Comment: running "gcc -c -Q --help=optimizers <source> > zo" and checking for 'enabled' gives an awful lot of output, including inlining of functions called once and moving of loop invariants. Which tbh seems to be wrong for 'make debugging produce expected results'. But you could switch those optimisations off and see what happens

Comment: to Tom Tanner, what is "tbh"?tks

Comment: tbh => to be honest. I have spent too much time talking to people who speak text message recently

Comment: gcc -c -Q -help=optimizers -I../../include -I../bayes      -I/usr/local/apache2/include  -D__LINUX__ standalone.c >x--------this command give rise to many errors,but it got compiled if i drop "-Q -help=optimizers"

Comment: --help, not -help (though it's not that obvious from the typeface used)