# Why does GDB "next" show the constructor line twice?

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb

When using gdb "next" tracing the code below,

```
int main(){
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(28);
}
```

The second line `vector<int> a` was displayed twice.
Please see the screen shot[image]

Can anybody tell me why the line was displayed twice?

The source code t.cpp was compiled using

- g++ -g -std=c++11 t.cpp,
- on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
  with g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

I noticed the post [gdb,why "next" show each source line twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576409/gdb-why-next-show-each-source-line-twice), but no answer was given there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could possibly have something to do with the destructor being called as the function returns? You might want to examine the generated machine code to see what your program does.

Answer (score 5):

Because G++ assigns the code for objects' constructors to the same line as their destructors, as 'Some programmer dude' suggested. Have a look at the resulting assembly over at the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/KAZAig) website.

This is probably done because destructors are called when leaving the scope, which can lead to multiple objects being destroyed on the same line. Showing '}' multiple times in the debugger is not very helpful as the user can't see which object is to be destructed next.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent GDB from showing the source the second time? It is annoying for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same "problem": The line is displayed twice in the debugger, because the compiler generates an extra debug-position for the destructor, regardless of the debug info you use (tried STABS, DWARF) or the debug level (tried the lowest -g1).

But this behaviour may be usefull, because now it is possible to do a "step into" the destructor (if you have the debug info and source for it).